# Creating pod from existing framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, dependency-management

SDK which I have to use in my project is a very big one and I don't want (at least I don't see why I should) add it directly to project directory.

I thought it'd be great to create a private cocoapod which will make working with this SDK easier for everyone in this project.

---

So, here is my problem... I don't have a clue how to create a cocoapod with a framework inside...

When I got to the repo directory and do something like: `pod lib create SampleSDK` I get everything set up but, wher I should add this ready framework to make everything work? I guess I should add it to `Pods` target but where exactly? Because when I've decided to drag and drop it to `Frameworks/iOS` and selected to copy files if necessary I cannot use this SDK from a sample project connected with this cocoapod.